# Get the last value of a string/array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I used the following PHP code, which gave me the output below:

```
$datetimearray = explode(" ", $mydatetime);
$last = pos($datetimearray);
var_dump($last);
```

**Output:**
*string(10) "2014-06-07" string(10) "2014-06-08" string(10) "2014-06-09"*

I am not sure what this means. It is not an array, but also not a single string.
How do I get the last value (2014-06-09) of this?

**UPDATE**
Here is the full code (CakePHP). I forgot I was in a loop...

```
foreach ($valuations as $valuation):
  $mydatetime = $valuation['Valuation']['timestamp'];
  $datetimearray = explode(" ", $mydatetime);
  $last = pos($datetimearray);
  var_dump($last);
endforeach;
```

Comment: You don't need `explode` and arrays at all: `substr(strrchr($mydatetime, ' '), 1)`

Comment: Please post the whole code, because this is obviously run within a loop of some sorts.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry, I am in a loop.

Comment: I updated the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the valuations are already sorted by date:

```
$last_valuation = end($valuations); // inspect last element of array
$last_date = strtok($last_valuation['Valuation']['timestamp'], ' ');
```

See also: [`end()`](http://php.net/end) [`strtok()`](http://php.net/strtok)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that you don't do this in a loop? pos() is an alias for current(), so each call returns the current element of your array.

To get the last element, take a look at end() (http://php.net/manual/de/function.end.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way using `count` minus 1 to grab the last item in an array:

```
$datetimearray = explode(" ", $mydatetime);
$last = $datetimearray[count($datetimearray) - 1)];
var_dump($last);
```